# Flutter stuck at resolving dependencies

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Anyone here encounters flutter being stucked at `Resolving Dependencies` when creating new app. I have been installing flutter for the last 4 days.

I already try various solutions and nothing's work. I already make sure that the checklist required is all checked.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a similar problem. Begin by examining any errors in your Flutter setup using flutter doctor. If there are no issues, navigate to your ./android/build.gradle file and adjust the version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:. Consider using lower versions, as it may address compatibility issues between Android Studio and Flutter. Once you've resolved the dependencies, remember to revert back to the original Gradle version to avoid encountering errors.